# python how to dynamically print index number of items and print the items

Tags: python

This is my code so far:

```
things = ['humans', 'fish', 'plants', 'planets', 'stars']

print('These are types of things we learnt so far:')
for thing in things:
    print(thing, end=', ')
print()

print(len(things))
the_input = int(input('Now please enter a number which you want to print: '))
print(f'You have chosen {the_input} which is {things[the_input]}.')

# the unfinished rest:
# the_input = int(input('Now please enter a number which you want to print: '))
# if the_input == the index number of indexes of things list,
# then print:
# You have chosen {the_input} which is {things[the_input]}
```

This is my expected output:

```
These are types of things we learnt so far:
1) humans, 2) fish, 3) plants, 4) planets, 5) stars

Now please enter a number which you want to print:
2 # this is the input of terminal, not the output of print(the_input)
You have chosen 2 which is fish.
```

For this code I don't know how to do this (there maybe other issues but I'm not yet aware of them):

1. The first print statement to show `index_number) each_list_item`
2. to omit the last `,` which is shown in my code if you run it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use enumerate and decrease index input:

```
things = ['humans', 'fish', 'plants', 'planets', 'stars']

print(*[f'{idx}) {thing}' for idx, thing in enumerate(things, 1)], sep=', ', end='\n\n')

the_input = int(input('Now please enter a number which you want to print:\n'))
print(f'You have chosen {the_input} which is {things[the_input-1]}.')

# 1) humans, 2) fish, 3) plants, 4) planets, 5) stars

# Now please enter a number which you want to print:
# 2
# You have chosen 2 which is fish.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use combination of `enumerate` + `str.join`:

```
print('These are types of things we learnt so far:')
print(', '.join(f'{i}) {s}' for i, s in enumerate(things, 1)))
```

---

```
These are types of things we learnt so far:
1) humans, 2) fish, 3) plants, 4) planets, 5) stars
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, you should use the `enumerate` method. As described by the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The **next**() method of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.

```py
print('These are types of things we learnt so far:')
print(', '.join(f'{i}) {s}' for i, s in enumerate(things, start=1)))
```